# How to use GPU of Dual AMD FirePro D300 in my C++ calculations on MacOS?

Tags: c++, opencl, gpu

I have a MacPro computer with Dual AMD FirePro D300 GPU based on it. So I want to use that GPU for increasing my calculations in C++ on MacOS.

Can you provide me with some useful information on this subject? I need to boost my C++ calculations on my MacPro. This is my C++ code, I can change it as it needs to achieve the acceleration. But what should I read first, to use GPU of AMD FirePro D300 on MacOS? What should I know before I start to learn this hard work?

Comment: CUDA API is for Nvidia devices only...

Comment: Under macos with ATI card OpenCL should be an option: https://developer.apple.com/opencl/

Comment: You should probably look at algorithmic and CPU-based optimisations first, as these are easier and more portable than using GPGPU.

Comment: Another option is using compute shaders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before starting, as you say the hard work, you should know the basic concept of using GPU in distinction to CPU. In a very abstract way I will try to give this concept.

- Programming is to give `data` and `instruction` to processor, so processor will `work` on your `data` with that `instruction`.
- If you give one instruction and some data to CPU - CPU will work on your data step by step alternately. For example, CPU will execute the same instruction on each part of array in a loop.
- In GPU you have hundreds of little CPUs that will execute one instruction concurrently. Again, as example, if you have the same array of data, and the same instruction GPU will take your array, split it between CPUs and execute your instruction on all data concurrently.
- CPU is really fast in executing one instruction.
- One thread of GPU is much slower in it. (Like comparing Ferrari to a bus.)

And what I am implying to is that you will see the benefits of GPU only if you have to do huge amount of `independent` calculations in parallel.

Comment: You mean GPU it's like a parallel computing? I have been working for sometime with parallel programming so I know what it is but I had never use GPU before. I was using separate network clusters to compute heavy calculations synchronously :)

Comment: @JavaRunner Yes, it is parallel computing. You give one command and thousands of threads execute this one command independently of each other.